# UINavigationController Bar color update in viewWillAppear updating after visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In an app I am working on, I have a `UITabBarController` that contains views that are each in a `UINavigationController`.

One of the views is a settings screen where a user can change the color scheme of the app.  When they do so, and switch to another screen, every component that is supposed to change color is already changed EXCEPT for the background of the `UINavigationController`.  It updates a fraction of a second after it is visible, so there is an annoying flicker.

This is a simplification of my `viewWillAppear` (which I just tested to make sure it still causes the error)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UIColor *foreGround = [self.settings getForegroundColor];
    UIColor *backGround = [self.settings getBackgroundColor];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = backGround;
    self.navigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = backGround;
    self.view.backgroundColor = backGround;

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = foreGround;
    self.navigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = foreGround;
    self.view.tintColor = foreGround;
}
```

What is even stranger, I have a `UIBarButtonItem` in the `UINavigationController` Bar that I go to, and it's color has updated before the view is visible, but the background behind it still needs to update.

Things I have tried:

- `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];`
- `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setNeedsDisplay];`
- `viewWillLayoutSubviews`
- Doing either of those from `NSNotification` that is sent to the this viewController when the user changed the color setting (long before they click the tab bar to look at the offending viewController).

Is there a way to force it to draw off screen, or something so This flicker won't occur?  I do not understand why it is insisting on updating when visible, when I put this in the main viewController's `viewWIllAppear`.

Does anybody know how to make a UINavigationController's Bar update before coming onscreen when the UINavigationController is embedded in a tab bar controller?

Comment: have you tried to put it into viewDidLoad instead?

Comment: @LucaIaco It is in viewDidLoad for the initial loading, and it does work correctly then.  But if I am in the main screen, click to the settings screen (to change the color), and then back, viewDidLoad is not called again, so it does not help for future changes.

Comment: oks. Have you tried to put them into "viewWillLayoutSubviews" ?

Comment: @LucaIaco Did after your suggestion, and unfortunately, still does not fix it.  Still updates after the view has come onscreen.

Comment: mmm. Try to set the navigation bar properties directly from where you send the notification, using this "[UINavigationBar appearance]". Setting this appearance, you should apply all modification like tintColor and so on, on all existing and future navigation bars. So you could use it like "[UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];"

Comment: @LucaIaco Unfortunately, same problem.  Still shows up after viewWillAppear.  I took some time making a sample project that only shows my issue, so I didn't have to worry about side effects from the rest of my app messing with it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `UINavigationControllerDelegate`. Here is a snippet in Swift from my app that should work:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.delegate = self
        reloadNav()
    }

    func reloadNav() {
        //Put custom code to change UINavigationController however you want.

        //Animation is not necessary, but it is nice.
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35) {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = nil

            //This is the default iOS tint color
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2901960784, green: 0.5019607843, blue: 0.9019607843, alpha: 1)

            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
        }       
    }
}

extension ViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

        if let vc2 = toVC as? ViewController {
            vc2.reloadNav()
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

**TL;DR** Use the `func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?` in the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` to perform your custom animation by accessing the reload func in your view controller.

I hope this helps, let me know if you need more clarification/help. Good luck!